# Problems with git and merging updates from GitHub

Tags: git, merge

I recently downloaded a repository from GitHub and wanted to pull in additional updates.  I did the `$ git fetch upstream` and everything went perfectly, but when I did:
`$ git merge upstream/master`

A conflict arose and couldn't merge.  Now, when I go into terminal and look at my branches, it looks like this:

```
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/add_reports
origin/assets
origin/enhance_reports
origin/master
upstream/add_reports
upstream/assets
upstream/enhance_reports
upstream/master
```

any way to successfully? merge these redundant files?

Comment: What is the output of `git status` command in your working directory?

Comment: Those are branches, not files... They show that you have one remote named "origin" that has 4 branches, and another remote named "upstream" that has 4 identically-named, but not necessarily identical, branches...

Answer (score 0):

These are not files, they are branches. To resolve a conflict, you need to manually edit the conflicted files at the point where conflict markers appear.

Conflict markers look like this:

```
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
... some code ...
================
... some code ...
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Alternatively, you can just use the git reset command to irretrievably throw away your local changes.